# Rails 4 assets:precompile not working Nginx + Thin configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, thin

Please help me.
I have rails4 app runnig on vps.

I have thin in nginx config

```
upstream myapp {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
  server 127.0.0.1:3001;
  server 127.0.0.1:3002;
}
server {
  listen   80;
  server_name .example.com;

  access_log /var/www/myapp.example.com/log/access.log;
  error_log  /var/www/myapp.example.com/log/error.log;
  root     /var/www/myapp.example.com;
  index    index.html;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect  off;
  try_files /system/maintenance.html $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @ruby;
 }

  location @ruby {
   proxy_pass http://myapp;
  }
}
```

And this is my production enviroment settings

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
 config.serve_static_assets = true

 # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
 config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
 #  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
 config.assets.compile = true
 config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']
```

in public/assets/ i can see compiled js css and images smthing like manydigits.png
But when i going to my site there is 404 in assets

Answer (score 2):

```
  location ~ ^/(assets)/{
     root /var/www/myapp.example.com/public;
     expires max;
     add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
```

This code in nginx config fixed my asset problem